# Regular expression to find the space between words or combination of letter and number (not at end of line) and replace with comma

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have the following text :

```
D1CP009           000307108   NN000307108
```

I want a regular expression that would replace space with comma but not at end of line.

The output should be :

```
D1CP009,000307108,NN000307108
```

I have used the following regular expression in notepad++:
`\s+` to find the combination of space and replace with comma. 
But when using `\s+(?!$)`  this only find the last space in line.

**EDIT after using the answer:**

[image]

Comment: *when using `\s+(?!$)` this only find the last space in line.* - this is impossible, this pattern matches all spaces in the document but the last whitespace on a line (it may be a line break after blank lines, too).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **regex to match whitespace between words** is

```
\b\s+\b
\b\h+\b
```

In Notepad++, in order not to overmatch across lines, `\s` can be replaced with `\h`, horizontal whitespace pattern.

Here, `\b` word boundaries require a word char (letter, digits, `_`) before and after a chunk of 1+ whitespace chars.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Rx6FHX/1).

In this concrete case, you want to match **any 1 or more whitespaces that are not at the end of the line** may use the following regex:

```
\h++(?!$)
```

or  - if you need to match any kind of whitespace:

```
\s++(?!$)
```

and replace with `,`.

The `\h++` pattern will match 1 or more horizontal whitespaces possessively, without allowing backtracking into the pattern, and `(?!$)` negative lookahead will fail the match if the last matched whitespace is followed with end of line.

[image]

Comment: this is not able to find the space.

Comment: @vermaraj What do you mean it can't? I copied your text into NPP, ran the regex replacement, and pasted the results as a screenshot. If you need to remove all whitespaces, use `\s` instead of `\h`. Then just use `\s++(?!$)`.

Comment: @vermaraj: Try `\h+(?!\h|$)` / `\s+(?!\s|$)` and replace with `,`. These are  patterns providing the same functionality but without possessive quantifiers.

Comment: Well, it is the correct answer. No idea what is wrong with your NPP.

Comment: yes you are right, there was a problem with my NPP, i reinstalled the same and it works. don't know what happened earlier. Thanks.

Comment: @vermaraj Glad it finally worked. Please also consider upvoting my answer if it proved helpful.